# What is the fastest way of creating thumbnails with the help of Imagemagick

Tags: php, imagemagick

What is the fastest way of creating thumbnails of large image files with the help of Imagemagick?

- Result quality is not important
- Output format is not important
- Expected average thumbnail size ~ 200px
- Input files may be larger than 30MB (PSD files)

Comment: This may be of help: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/thumbnails/

Comment: If you are reading PSD make sure you only read the 'merged frame' that contains the merged image. The syntax for this is: file.psd[0]. It tells the reader to ignore the other frames.

Comment: thank you for [0] tip @dlemstra you are my hero today. I think it is also same for PDF and other layered formats. Am I right?

Comment: Other formats will just provide you with the first frame but that should be okay when you create a thumbnail.